# Redimensionamento de imagem dds via software

Tags: c++, directx

estou com uma pequena dúvida, estava analisando os arquivos de um software em DirectX 8 e vi que o mesmo faz uma coisa que não consigo entender como, ele pega uma imagem base, vamos chamar de *frame.dds* e a redimensiona de uma resolução inicial de digamos **128x116** para algo do tipo **401x73**, isso tudo usando apenas DirectX creio eu e sem perder NADA de qualidade na imagem final, seguem exemplos das imagens em questão:

Inicial:

[image: frame.dds inicial]

Final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como isso é possível? alguem poderia me explicar? tentei fazer o mesmo usando sprites e no Sprite->Draw eu modificaria o scalling, até que funcionou mas perdi muita qualidade na imagem final, os cantos ficaram borrados e etc...

Comment: Procure na internet por Patch 9 ou 9 Patch. A técnica consiste em repetir ou esticar o meio da imagem, e manter os cantos sem distorção (imagine dividir a imagem em 9 pedaços, onde os 4 cantos não são distorcidos, o "meio superior" e o "meio inferior" só esticam ou repetem na horizontal, e o "meio esquerdo" e "meio direito" só esticam ou repetem na vertical. Só o quadradinho do meio que é esticado ou replicado nos 2 eixos.

Comment: Exemplo: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-7K_URaoOH2c/VPlhcOE1wFI/AAAAAAAAB00/tWeFG0wSfMs/s1600/nine-patch-image.png